# output-task.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'multiDrag' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I am getting this error when I am trying to update my state using props basically when my condition matches the flag would certainly go back to its initial state value but it is showing error in this case.

```
    var finalVal;

    if (
      typeof bigFinalValue === "undefined" ||
      bigFinalValue.length < 1 ||
      this.props.singleDrag === true
    ) {
      console.log("here he is", this.props.singleDrag);
      finalVal = <Content>{task.word}</Content>;
      this.props.multiDrag = false;
    }

    if (
      (typeof bigFinalValue === "undefined" || bigFinalValue.length > 1) &&
      this.props.multiDrag === true
    ) {
      console.log("bigFinalValue", bigFinalValue);
      console.log("selectionCount", selectionCount);
      console.log("and here he is again...");
      finalVal = <Content>{bigFinalValue}</Content>;
      this.props.multiDrag = false;                                                         
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here the error is pretty obvious. You are trying to set props to false.

> this.props.multiDrag = false; //wrong

Props are READ ONLY. You can read the article below to get a better understanding how it works.

[https://itnext.io/what-is-props-and-how-to-use-it-in-react-da307f500da0#:~:text=%E2%80%9CProps%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20special%20keyword,from%20one%20component%20to%20another.&text=Furthermore%2C%20props%20data%20is%20read,be%20changed%20by%20child%20components](https://itnext.io/what-is-props-and-how-to-use-it-in-react-da307f500da0#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CProps%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20special%20keyword,from%20one%20component%20to%20another.&text=Furthermore%2C%20props%20data%20is%20read,be%20changed%20by%20child%20components).

Comment: tried to set state here but it also getting me multiple re-rendering errors that's why hit and run this approach, thanks.

Comment: Then you definitely structured something wrong. You can create state in this component and setState after every update, as you need.